# How should i show select title with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello Guys Please Help me for this I didn't how I show select title. I want to show above When should we call you?.

please check my code Thanks:-

```
 <select name="myfirst" title="When should we call you?">
    <option class="optnoval"></option>
    <option value="today" id="df">today</option>
    <option value="tommorow" id="df">tommorow</option>
    <option value="sunday" id="dfd">sunday</option>
 </select>
```

Please check online codepen code link:- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EQBbyG

Comment: *When should we call you?* is showing as a tooltip when you hover on the `select`. Where do expect it to show?

Comment: so please check my codepen live code please tell me how i show on front without click on select option Thanks

Comment: i don't think native tooltip can be styled

Comment: You mean you want to put it on `<label>`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label?

Comment: Titles are shown when the mouse hovers over the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `jQuery` you can select all the `<select>` elements with a `title` attribute, and copy its value into the first `<option>`.

```js
$("select[title] option:first-child").text(function(i, oldtext) {
  if (oldtext.trim() == '') {
    return $(this).parent().attr("title");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="myfirst" title="When should we call you?">
    <option class="optnoval"></option>
    <option value="today">today</option>
    <option value="tommorow">tommorow</option>
    <option value="sunday" >sunday</option>
</select>
<select name="mytime" title="What time of day?">
    <option class="optnoval"></option>
    <option value="morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="afternoon" >Afternoon</option>
    <option value="evening">Evening</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello @barmar basically this is not my answer what i want i want title show on selectbox

Comment: You need to clarify the question. Where do you want to show the title? Do you want to replace the blank option with the title?

Comment: i don't want on label

Comment: where white blank show i want this title show overthere Thank you so much @barmar for help

Comment: please help me for this :)

Comment: Great Barmar thanks i just check this :) thank you so much i hope this work

Comment: Hello barmar is it possible to do with css this means without css

Comment: Hope you answer for this also

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS.

Comment: yeah but when this is css this is great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `<label>` in your HTML Markup.

```html
<label for="myfirst">When should we call you?</label>
<select name="myfirst" id="myfirst" title="When should we call you?">
 <option class="optnoval"></option>
 <option value="today" id="df">today</option>
 <option value="tommorow" id="df">tommorow</option>
 <option value="sunday" id="dfd">sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1 If using a label (which has the best support in Assistive Tools like screen readers because label only exist for that precise use), you can/should remove the title on select

Comment: This changes since the question is modified.